# Couldn't run single clojure test instead getting warning "cider no test at point"

Tags: clojure, cider

I'm using emacs as clojure development environment. My emacs config is [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/emacs.d)

I'm trying to run single test in my clojure project.

I've test file called core-test in the folder `test/getting-started/core-test.clj` folder. The contents of the file is -

```
(ns getting-started.core-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [getting-started.core :refer :all]))

(deftest a-test
  (testing "FIXME, I fail."
    (is (= 0 0))))
```

I would like to run the single test a-test.

I started cider using command `cider-jack-in`. Now I'm trying to run single test using command `M-x cider-test-run-test`.

[image: cider-test-run-test]

Now I'm getting warning ***no test at point***

[image: No test at point]

What is wrong I'm doing. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The java environment prohibits file names containing hyphens. Since Clojure namespaces ***can*** contain hyphens, they must be replaced with underscore characters in the filename.  I prefer to avoid hyphens in namespace names for this reason.  If you do include them, you must arrange it like:

```
namespace:   test.getting-started.core-test
filename:    test/getting_started/core_test.clj
```

If you would like to try a different method, please clone [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

Comment: I get the same error for repo that you mentioned.

Comment: I do not use emacs/cider. Did you try running it from the command line (my favorite)?